# creating a folder with custom icon viewable on BOTH Mac OS X and Windows

Tags: windows, macos, icons, directory

I am trying to make a folder that has a custom icon which would work on both a Windows and a Mac system. It is so that when it is downloaded onto a users computer the icon will work on any system running Windows or OS.

So far I understand how to make it work for any Windows PC (by creating a desktop.ini file, setting a relative path to an .ico file within the folder and then hiding these files), and I have managed to make it work for a single Mac OS X system (by opening file info and dragging an icon in). However once doing this it seems to disrupt the PC icon, so it doesn't work anymore.

Is there some sort of solution that works across platforms?

Thanks a lot